# Laravel relationship query - get all completed projects

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Looking for some advice on creating an eloquent query.

I have 3 tables

- Projects
- Tasks
- UserTasks

A project has tasks, and in usertasks we save the task and user id so we know it has been completed by the user. Now I need to query all projects that have been completed by the user, so projects that have tasks where all tasks for that project have been completed.

I can't seem to wrap my head around it, I am trying to create a scope for this.

```
public function scopeisCompleted($query)
{
    $query = $query->whereHas('userTasks', function ($query) {
        $query->where('user_id', '=', Auth::user()->id);
    })->get();

    return $query;    
}
```

I can't seem to get my head around how to make sure all tasks for that project are completed by the user.

Any advice on moving forward?

Comment: I think you can found it here. you need to link your relationships from your models and just called them with relationships for user. https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships

Comment: I have created relationships for all 3, I am unsure how to query for projects that have all tasks completed. I can get all tasks for the project, but how to create one query for projects that have all the tasks in it completed by a specific user I am not sure.

Is there a specific part in that documentation that I should focus on? I have read through it multiple times but can't seem to make the connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'd need something like this:

```
public function scopeisCompleted($query)
{
    $query = $query->whereHas('userTasks', function ($query) {
        $query->where('user_id', '=', Auth::user()->id)
            ->whereHas('task', function ($query) {
                $query->where('completed', 1);
            });
    })->get();

    return $query;    
}
```

So as long as the `task` relationship is setup for the `UserTask` model and the column is `completed`, if not change it to the correct one.

I just read your question in more detail, if you need to check that all tasks are completed then that would be a bit more complicated, the query would need to find how many tasks there are and if that number matches the total completed tasks.

**Update**

I think I understand a bit more now on what you're trying to do:

```
public function scopeisCompleted($query)
{
    $query = $query->with('tasks', 'userTasks')->whereHas('userTasks', function ($query) {
        $query->where('user_id', '=', Auth::user()->id);
    })->get();

    return $query;    
}
```

as mentioned in the comment, I'm not sure what model this scope is being used on so this might still be incorrect, but here I've added the `->with('tasks')` so that once the query results have been returned, the tasks for the project can be compared to the user completed tasks for the project, although it should still be possible to do this in the query rather than in PHP.

```
if (count($results->tasks)) == count($results->userTasks)) {
    // complete
}
```

I will need to think about it later, I might have the wrong syntax for what you're trying to do and the `with` might need to be something like `->with('tasks.userTasks')`.

Comment: Thanks @martincarlin87, the UserTask table has no completed column, in fact there is only a row created in the UserTask table if it has been completed. There is no row for tasks that have not been completed.

And with your scope, wouldn't it only get get projects where has tasks that have been completed? Not projects that has all tasks completed?

Comment: hmm, ok, sounds like `whereHas` would be the right Eloquent method to use here instead, let me try updating the answer, I'm just slightly confused where the scope is being used (which model).

Comment: The scope is being used in the Project model hoping to end up with $projects->isCompleted() which returns all projects that the current logged in user has completed(UserTasks) all tasks(Tasks) for.

Comment: I have set your answer to completed, as it is working. It's not fully getting the completed projects in the scope function alone, but at least it's working thanks for the help.